# HTML from a webpage does not display foreign language characters correctly

Tags: python, http, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

Apologies if the title is misleading.

I am trying to find out the language of a given song by querying a lyric site and then using CLD2 to check the language of the lyrics. However, with certain songs (such as the example given below) the foreign language characters aren't being encoded properly, which means that CLD2 throws up this error: `input contains invalid UTF-8 around byte 2121 (of 32761)`

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cld2

response = requests.get(https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/blackpink/ddududdudu.html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
counter = 0
for item in soup.select("div"):
    counter+=1
    if counter == 21:
        lyrics = item.get_text()
        checklang(lyrics)
        print("Lyrics found!")
        break

def checklang(lyrics):
    try:
        isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(lyrics)
        language = re.search("ENGLISH", str(details))
        
        if language == None:
            print("foreign lang")
                      
        if len(re.findall("Unknown", str(details))) < 2:
            print("foreign lang")
                      
        if language != None:
            print("english")
            pass
```

It is also worth mentioning that this is not limited to non-latin characters and sometimes occurs with apostrophes or other punctuation.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening or what I could do to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Requests` should make educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers.

Unfortunately, in given example, `response.encoding` shows `ISO-8859-1` in despite of `response.content` shows `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Here's my solution based on [*Response Content* paragraph in the `requests` documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import cld2
import pycld2 as cld2

def checklang(lyrics):
        #try:
        isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(lyrics)
        # language = re.search("ENGLISH", str(details))
        for detail in details:
            print(detail)

response = requests.get('https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/blackpink/ddududdudu.html')

print(response.encoding)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'                         ### key change ###

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
counter = 0
for item in soup.select("div"):
    counter+=1
    if counter == 21:
        lyrics = item.get_text()
        checklang(lyrics)
        print("Lyrics found!")
        break
```

**Output**: `\SO\65630066.py`

```
ISO-8859-1
('ENGLISH', 'en', 74, 833.0)
('Korean', 'ko', 20, 3575.0)
('Unknown', 'un', 0, 0.0)
Lyrics found!
```