# Hebrew in Python request response?

Tags: python, http, encoding, get, hebrew

in python 3 I am sending a get request to a website which has the following text in Hebrew language:

```
לימודי הסמכה בטכניון | רישום
```

But when I print the response like this:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(response.content)
```

I get:

```
\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\x9e\xd7\x95\xd7\x93\xd7\x99 \xd7\x94\xd7\xa1\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x94 \xd7\x91\xd7\x98\xd7\x9b\xd7\xa0\xd7\x99\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f | \xd7\x94\xd7\x96\xd7\x93\xd7\x94\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa
```

How can I fix this and print normal output?

Here are my headers since they may help.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'close'
}
```

Comment: You may get the correct answer. It seems that your terminal (so `print`) cannot print UTF-8 characters, so Python uses escapes ONLY to your terminal. You should check with browsers if you get correct results. Do not trust console (and `print`)

Comment: I am using pycharm terminal, how can I fix this?

Comment: First in your debugger what do you see under response.text? you need to find the right encoder for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML from a webpage does not display foreign language characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630066/html-from-a-webpage-does-not-display-foreign-language-characters-correctly)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _response_ headers.

Answer (score 0):

try (response.text).decode('cp856')  or (response.content).decode('cp856')

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying bytes that you get back, but the data is bytes encoded in UTF-8. Is this maybe what you expect to see?

```
>>> b"\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\x9e\xd7\x95\xd7\x93\xd7\x99 \xd7\x94\xd7\xa1\xd7\x9e\xd7\x9b\xd7\x94 \xd7\x91\xd7\x98\xd7\x9b\xd7\xa0\xd7\x99\xd7\x95\xd7\x9f | \xd7\x94\xd7\x96\xd7\x93\xd7\x94\xd7\x95\xd7\xaa".decode()
'לימודי הסמכה בטכניון | הזדהות'
```