# How to handle broken emojis characters in Flask requests?

Tags: python, rest, flask, encoding, python-requests

My code returns broken emojis characters in a Flask service:

```
@app.route('/keyword_extraction', methods=['GET'])
def extract():
    text, parameters = _parse_parameters()
    if 'error' in parameters:
        return 'Error request parameters: {}'.format(parameters['error']), status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    result = keyword_extraction(text, **parameters)
    
    return result
```

If the input text is '“What is pop?” ', the result is a valid python dict structure when I debug it in Pycharm as below, as there are no broken characters.:

```
{'text': '  “What is pop?” ', 'result': [], 'category': 'beauty', 'status': 'failed'}
```

However, the requests.request return broken characters:

```
'{"text":"  ğŸ¥°â€œWhat is pop?â€� ","result":[],"category":"ç¾�å¦†","status":"failed"}'
```

The request code is:

```
text = '  “What is pop?” '

text = urllib.parse.quote(text, safe='')
url = 'http://localhost:5001/keyword_extraction?text=' + text + '&channel=beauty'

r = requests.request('GET', url)
r = r.text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML from a webpage does not display foreign language characters correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630066/html-from-a-webpage-does-not-display-foreign-language-characters-correctly) I guess `r.encoding = 'utf-8'` could help before retrieving `r.text`?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Also, r=r.json() also worked.